# how to increase the api level in android SDK?

Tags: api

I  am currently working on  creating notification from android application.
For general notification with single action,we will do the normal procedure to create...but in order to include more number of actions on that particular notification,I have to use notificatiomcompat.builder and so on..and finally add action .
Problem here is that notificationcompat can't be resolved.
The packages are in higher api..by my SDK has up to api level14.
So can any one tell what and where I have to download and install to increase my api level  in clear manner?

Answer (score 0):

"SDK Manager" is a tool provided with your Android SDK, you can find it in the root directory of ANDROID SDK.

It is very easy to use.Run the utility ,it can fetch version information from server, what you need to do is to choose and download what you want. Then , switch to different SDK version in you Eclipse.